# GlViewport-code doesn't work in one specific screen?

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, viewport

I am currently working on a small game using LibGDX and Java.

However, I have found one oddly specific problem. I want the game to resize so that it never has to be cropped and so it never has to cut anything off - basically just setting the viewport so everything still fits onto the screen on resize. Sounds simple.

Now, I have the code for that in place. All of my screens extend one BaseScreen in which I defined the following code:

```
@Override
public void resize (int width, int height) {
    Vector2 size = Scaling.fit.apply(Constants.GAME_WIDTH, Constants.GAME_HEIGHT, width, height);
    int viewportX = (int)(width - size.x) / 2;
    int viewportY = (int)(height - size.y) / 2;
    int viewportWidth = (int)size.x;
    int viewportHeight = (int)size.y;
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
}
```

(Note, I have not written this code by myself, it is one of the few pieces of code I searched online for as I had no previous experience with LibGDX)

Now, this code works absolutely fine in almost every screen - just not in the RoomScreen, which is the screen where the main gameplay is happening. Which is quite a bummer, as it basically makes the game look really shitty except for multiples of my game size (the constants are set as 480 and 272).

Now, I have absolutely no idea why this is the case. I read that this might be because transforms are pushed, but not pulled afterwards, but I did not find any instance of this in my code.

I also tested wether the code is executed, and it indeed is. All variables are correctly set, it simply doesn't work.

If any of you is able to help me, I would be unbelievably thankful!

The full code is currently only available in my Dropbox, as my own Git server recently crashed. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/evvw5kiqcfos7fu/AADwogpkwl1RWj2QcI6eePyda?dl=0
(I am terribly sorry that I am only able to share it this way, but I am afraid that sharing every relevant class in this post itself would in the end result in pasting all my code here, making it almost unreadable. If any of you has a better idea than this, please tell me, I'll gladly share it otherwise!)

If you are wondering, the screen classes are in the folder "screen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after doing a metric butt-ton of debugging I seem to finally have figured out how to solve this - quite peculiar - problem, even though I don't really like the solution.

I am not sure why, but the LibGDX people chose to make a FrameBuffer set the viewport on every `begin()` call. This is problematic in so far that on an end() call, it seems like the original viewport is not properly restored, even though it should be as far as I can gather from the source code.

This means that the fix is actually rather simple, just reset the viewport after the faulty FrameBuffer `end()`. Of course this is by far not the ideal solution, as it does make the game rather stuttery, but I'll have to resort to this if I cannot figure out shaders properly.